# React Grid : How to make a Grid Item to fill empty spaces

Tags: reactjs, gridview

I'm developing a React web UI. 
I have 3 sections containing contents that needs to be correctly scaled depending on the user device screen size.
I use the Grid React container and can't manage to format the layout as I would like.

My 3 sections are not the same size so if my grid is 2 columns wide, the 3rd section will begin where the most bigger among the two other ends. you will find pictures of what i have now and what i would like to have at the end of this text.

For now, I tried to look at all the React Grid properties that could solve my problem, even reformatted some of my code to use divs instead of using React Grid but nothing that i found worked.

Basically this is the code I use :

```
render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Grid container spacing={16}>
                <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
                    <Section title={title1}>
                           CONTENT 1
                    </Section>
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
                        <Section title={title2}>
                            CONTENT 2
                        </Section>
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
                        <Section title={title3>
                            CONTENT 3
                        </Section>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
```

And this is what i get : [Actual Grid Layout](https://ibb.co/xJHSq1q)
And this is what I would like to have : [Wanted Layout](https://ibb.co/FWJYQPr)

Is there anyway I can get the layout I would like using the React Grid container ?

I'm still a React rookie, Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't want to use css `grid` or `flex-box`. You can easily accomplish this layout using css.

[Here is complete guide to use css grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

Answer (score 0):

Also try this. I am not sure it is working fine

```
  return (
  <React.Fragment>
    <Grid container spacing={16}>
      <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
        <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
          <Section title={title1}>
            CONTENT 1
          </Section>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
          <Section title={title3}>
            CONTENT 3
          </Section>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>

    <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
      <Section title={title2}>
        CONTENT 2
      </Section>
    </Grid>
  </React.Fragment >
);
```